# Assertion of Web Element's text fails even if assertion window shows that both texts are indentical

Tags: java, selenium, assertion

Hi So at first I'll describe my task. So I have to write automated test with the following steps:
    1.Login into page https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/login
    2.After login make an assertion of Following text " You logged into a secure area! ".
    3.Click logout button
    4.Check text assertion of You logged out of the secure area!

So this is what I did I wrote this using Page factory1st class for login page: https://pastebin.com/CgJY84Te 2nd class for after login page: https://pastebin.com/KpgWunDt

and Junit test class: https://pastebin.com/GkEm4TrG

So it works as it supposed to work but when it get to 1st assertion, it fails, so I have checked assertion and in assertion, there was a difference (...element).getText() returned such as text"You logged into a secure area!

×"

Ok it seems that text in this alert has some spaces new line and X at the end.

I have changed assertion to

`Assert.assertEquals(afterLoginTest.returnAlertElementText(), "You logged into a secure area!\r\n" +

```
            "×")`
```

Run test once again and it failed.... . When i open assertion window there is lack of any difference. So can anyone tell me what it fails?Look at attached screenshot(https://prnt.sc/nqcel5)I am fed up with that shit, lost 2 hours to find solution.

Comment: Unless you have to assert that the new lines are in the text, I would suggest that you remove them and then assert the revised text.  Something like String revisedText = yourString.replace('\n', '') and then run your assert against revisedText instead.

Comment: Try playing around with your xpath as that x doesn't seem to be in the text you are trying to capture. Try changing it to something like  `//*[@id="flash"]/text()`

Comment: As mentioned already try getting the string needed for assertion and get rid of the extra text. You could write something like this `public String returnAlertElementText() {

        String  textToAssert = alert.getText();
        String [] strArr = textToAssert.split("\\n");
        return strArr[0];
    }`